# compare two dataframes and append the data in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample dataframe `df1`

```
id  user_id     name             email       
1     1        John         John@example.com
2     2        Alves        alves@example.com
3     3        Kristein     kristein@example.com
4     4        James        james@example.com
```

The second dataframe `df2`

```
id      user       user_email_1            user_email_2         status
1      Sanders     sanders@example.com                          active
2      Alves       alves111@example.com   alves@example.com     active
3      Micheal     micheal@example.com                          active
4      James       james@example.com                            delete
```

How can I add the status data from `df2` to `df1` if

`user_id` of `df1` and `id` of `df2`

`name` of `df1` and `user` of `df2`

`email` of `df1` matches with `user_email_1` or `user_email_2` of `df2` matches and drops the not matched records?

Desired Result `df1`:

```
id   user_id    name       email                status
2      2        Alves     alves@example.com     active
4      4        James     james@example.com     delete
```

For example:

As `alves@example.com` from `df1` matches with `user_email_2`, it appended the status data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,left_on=['user_id','name','email'],right_on=['id','user','user_email'],how='left').drop(['id_x','id_y','user'],1)`

Answer (score -1):

You should use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df1.merge(df2.reset_index(), how='inner', left_on=['name', 'email', 'id'], right_on=['user', 'user_email', 'index'])
```

Comment: if id is index. Since you mentioned you can use join i thought id is the index

Answer (score -1):

Rearrange your dataframe `df2` to get only one `user_email` column then merge the two dataframes and keep wanted columns:

```
df2 = df2.set_index(['id', 'user', 'status']).stack() \
         .rename('user_email').reset_index()

out = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['user_id', 'name', 'email'],
                         right_on=['id', 'user', 'user_email'],
                         suffixes=('', '2')) \
          [['id', 'user_id', 'name', 'email', 'status']]
```

```
>>> out

   id  user_id   name              email  status
0   2        2  Alves  alves@example.com  active
1   4        4  James  james@example.com  delete
```

> Where is it using the column user_email_2

The columns `user_email_1` and `user_email_2` are stacked into one column. After the transformation, `df2` looks like:

```
>>> df2

   id     user  status       level_3            user_email
0   1  Sanders  active  user_email_1   sanders@example.com
1   2    Alves  active  user_email_1  alves111@example.com
2   2    Alves  active  user_email_2     alves@example.com
3   3  Micheal  active  user_email_1   micheal@example.com
4   4    James  delete  user_email_1     james@example.com
```

Comment: Where is it using the column `user_email_2` in your answer?

Comment: The columns `user_email_1` and `user_email_2` are stacked into one column.

Comment: @Digital404. Is it what you expect? If yes and if the answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept answer please.

Comment: No, we can't stack the email into a single column. I've mentioned empty in few cells, but it could be not empty. In that case, stacking wont help.

Comment: Are you sure. The output is what you expect. Can you show me when this doesn't work? If you want match `user_email_1` OR `user_email_2`, it doesn't matter if emails are in the same column.